# AngularJs : prevent $http send request to server repeatedly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am newly with angularJS (v1.6.x). I have some problems when I worked with angularJs's $http service (GET, DELETE, PUT and POST). It was occurred after I click to any routes ( swapped route many times ) and I'm back to previous route, then make perform any action (Create, edit or delete). Is is problem in angularJS ? How should I do to prevent this recursion ?

**This is What I tried :**

```js
app.factory('UserModel', ['$http', '$routeParams', 'env', '$q', function($http, $routeParams, env) {
            const user = {};
            user.get = get;
            user.create = create;
            user.destroy = destroy;
            user.update = update;

            return user;


            function create(data) {
                var config = {
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': "applicatio/json"
                    }
                };

                return $http.post(env.APP_URL + "/api/v1/users", data, config);
            }
        }]);
```

**In my Controller**

```js
app.controller('UserComponentControler', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'UserModel', function($rootScope, $scope, UserModel) {

        $rootScope.$on('modal:on:result', function(event, result) {

        if (result.status) {
            if (result.resultCode === $rootScope.window.CREATE) {
                UserModel.create(result.data).then(res => {
                    if (res.status === 200) {
                        $scope.page.load(0);
                        $scope.$emit('modal:on:create:callback', {
                            created: true
                        });
                    }
                }, err => {
                    $scope.$emit('modal:on:create:callback', {
                        created: false,
                        message: "Some fields have error with server!"
                    });
                    console.log(err);
                });
            } else if (result.resultCode === $rootScope.window.DELETE) {
                userId = result.user.id;
                UserModel.destroy(userId).then(res => {
                    if (res.status === 200) {
                        $scope.page.load($scope.page.props.current);
                        $scope.$emit('modal:on:alert', {
                            deleted: true,
                            message: {
                                title: "Message",
                                body: "User has beed deleted successfully!"
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                }, err => {
                    $scope.$emit('modal:on:alert', {
                        deleted: false,
                        message: {
                            title: "Message",
                            body: "Server Error Occured!"
                        }
                    });
                    console.log(err);
                });
            } else if (result.resultCode === $rootScope.window.EDIT) {
                UserModel.update(result.data, result.data.id).then(res => {
                    if (res.status === 200) {
                        $scope.page.load($scope.page.props.current);
                    }
                }, err => {
                    $scope.$emit('modal:on:update:callback', {
                        updated: false,
                        message: "Some fields have error with server!"
                    });
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }
        }

    });     

}]);
```

**After I swapped route from /home to /users 7 of times**
[image]

Comment: You must understand about `$scope.$emit` event.

Comment: I used it for share data and trigger other controller

Comment: thanks for reminding me!

Comment: Try using a service for http and use promise. So the api call will happen only once and you can share the data between controllers. I hope this is what you are looking. :)